# Mail using custom form in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

can anyone help me to learn me how i send a mail from a custom form on product page of magento 1.9 ? 
I am new in magento .

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom module with the controller. In your form action enter the controller URL which you have created. On form submit you can get the submitted data in your controller and from there you can write your mail function to send the mail and you can redirect the user to the same product page where they submitted the form using this function $this->_redirectReferer(). To send email using Magento template way you can refer to this link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087345/custom-email-sending-in-magento-custom-module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087345/custom-email-sending-in-magento-custom-module.)

Comment: Actually i create a form on catalog/product/view.phtml and i just want to know  that  what action i should write in form for submit it and what the mail function coding i will use

Comment: You need to create your own controller in a new module and you need to give that url to form action to get the data and send mail. Do you have idea on how to create a module and controller?

Comment: No i have no idea how to create a module and controller, Please help me how i create this

Comment: Follow the steps in this tutorial to create a module and controller https://www.pierrefay.com/magento-training/create-a-controller-tutorial.html

Comment: ok i follow this tutorial. If i will get any problem then i will ping you and thanks for give me suggestion.

Comment: Ok I will help you if you have any problem.

Comment: Hi  Venkatesh , I followed this tutorial and create all files as in it, but when  i call controller it show 404 not found error. Please help me

Comment: Are you able to see your module in System-> Configuration-> Advanced -> Disable Modules Output?

Comment: No ,not available there this module

Comment: Have u added Namespace_Module.xml file in app/etc/modules folder?

Comment: app/code/local/Pfay/Films/etc/config.xml   =>                                                          <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
     <modules>
        <Pfay_Films>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Pfay_Films>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <routeurfrontend>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Pfay_Films</module>
                 <frontName>films</frontName>
              </args>
           </routeurfrontend>
       </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>

Comment: app/code/local/Pfay/Films/controllers/IndexController.php                                  => <?php
class Pfay_Films_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
     echo 'test index' ;
   }
   public function mamethodeAction()
   {
     echo 'test mamethode';
    }
}

Comment: app/etc/modules/Pfay_Films.xml                                                                                 =><?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config>
      <modules>
        <Pfay_Films>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
         </Pfay_Films>
       </modules>
    </config>

Comment: these three files i have created please check

Comment: I have created the same files and tried and it is working fine for me. Please clear your cache and check Again.

Comment: Yaa , It's working . Thankyou So Much .

Comment: But now how  i apply mail function using this controller ,please tell me .

Comment: Do u want to use just php mail function to send mail or u want to use magento template to send email.

Comment: I want to use magento process not simple core.Please guide me.

Comment: Please try to follow these steps in the following link http://www.techflirt.com/magento-send-custom-email/. You will get a idea.

Comment: i am just confusing bcz in this case i have created a form on product page which is filled up by customer and when i will submit then information will sent on mail, so let me know what process should be use

Comment: I think it will not done using templates.

Comment: In the controller function use this $this->getRequest()->getParams() to get all the parameters from the submitted form. Compose the message based on the received parameters and use mail function to send mail to the respective email id. After that add this lines Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Success Message');$this->_redirectReferer();

Comment: If you want to use magento template then you need to follow the above link to create template.

Comment: Please send me that code for email bcz i have no idea about functions of magento.I am totally new in magneto have knowledge of admin panel only. So this time please help me

Comment: Put this under global tag in config.xml <template>
    <email>
        <custom_template translate="label" module="modulename">
            <label>any desired  name</label>
            <file>custom_template.html</file>
            <type>html</type>
        </custom_template>
    </email>
</template> and create custom_template.html in \app\locale\en_US\template\email. In that html file you copy any magento emails and put the same content and edit it based on your need.

Comment: In the controller action use this $formParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams()
$templateId = 'custom_template';
$senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name');
$senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email');
$sender = array('name' => $senderName,
    'email' => $senderEmail);
$recepientEmail = 'xxx@gmail.com';

Comment: $recepientName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name');
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
$translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
//variables you want to set in template
$vars = array('name' => $name, 'product_url' => $productpageUrl);
Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend');
Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
    ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recepientEmail, $recepientName, $vars, $storeId);
$translate->setTranslateInline(true);
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Success Message');
$this->_redirectReferer();

Comment: <form class="form-inline" action="films/index" method="post" id="myform">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Enter Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required>
  </div>

 

   <button  type="submit"   name="enquiry" > Submit</button>  
</form>(Actually this is my form on product page , now on films controller what code i write for send the mail of the content filled in form).

Comment: You write the codes which I have posted in the previous 2 comments in the indexAction of Controller.

Comment: ok i am trying this

Comment: Put this under global tag in config.xml (i cound not found global tag in config.xml)

Comment: please tell me the path of that config.xml

Comment: can you give me your skype id

Comment: I don't have skype. If there is no global tag just add it and put code inside it.

Comment: i have created template =><!--@subject Custom Template Form@-->
<!--@vars
{"var data.name":"Sender Name",
"var data.email":"Sender Email",
"var data.telephone":"Sender Telephone",
"var data.comment":"Comment"}
@-->
Name: {{var data.name}}
Email: {{var data.email}}
Telephone: {{var data.telephone}}

Comment: {{var data.comment}}

Comment: and films controller=><?php
class Pfay_Films_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
      Your given code here










   }
   
}

Comment: Is that not working?

Comment: now what i do ?

Comment: This page isn’t working

is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Comment: Are you getting this error on form submit?

Comment: Yes , bcz i confuse that where i declare the template name in controller by which it call that.Actuallu template name is  custom_template.html, template is given above  ,please give me code for controller according to this template

Comment: Use this in email template html <!--@subject Custom Template Form @-->
<!--@vars
{"store url=\"\"":"Store Url",
"var logo_url":"Email Logo Image Url",
"var logo_alt":"Email Logo Image Alt",
"var store.getFrontendName()":"Store Name",
@-->
<!--@styles
@-->

{{template config_path="design/email/header"}}
{{inlinecss file="email-inline.css"}}

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>

Comment: <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td class="email-heading">
                        <p>
                        Name: {{var name}}
                        Email: {{var email}}
                        </p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

{{template config_path="design/email/footer"}}

Comment: Put this in controller action

Comment: $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
$email = $this->getRequest()->getParam('email');
$templateId = 'description_edit_notification_email';
$senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name');
$senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email');
$sender = array('name' => $senderName,
    'email' => $senderEmail);
$recepientEmail = 'youremailaddress';
$recepientName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name');
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();

Comment: $translate = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');
$vars = array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email);
Mage::getDesign()->setArea('frontend');
Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
    ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recepientEmail, $recepientName, $vars, $storeId);
$translate->setTranslateInline(true);
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Thanks');
$this->_redirectReferer();

Comment: actually i m new also at this site so i have not read your comments. I am trying this now

Comment: $templateId = 'description_edit_notification_email'; please let me know is template id right or not

Comment: No sorry template id should be "custom_template" i.e the template id you have added in config.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config>
<global>
 <template>
 <email> <custom_template translate="label" module="modulename">
 <label>Custom Template</label>
 <file>custom_template.html</file>
 <type>html</type> </custom_template>
 </email> 
</template> 
</global>
     <modules>

Comment: <Pfay_Films>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Pfay_Films>
     </modules>
     <frontend>
       <routers>
          <routeurfrontend>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Pfay_Films</module>
                 <frontName>films</frontName>
              </args>
           </routeurfrontend>
       </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>

Comment: config.xml is now like this

Comment: Ok use $templateId = 'custom_template';

Comment: There has been an error processing your request
Exception printing is disabled by default for security reasons.

Error log record number: 207135410943

Comment: Hi, I think it works. it show thanks after submit form . Thank you very much.

Comment: But i did'nt get any mail .In recipt id i put my gmail id

Comment: Are you there??

Comment: Hi  Venkatesh , are you there??

Answer (score 0):

You can send an email by overwriting the `IndexController.php` of the `contacts` module. I have just created and added a new extension at `GitHub`. I just added the controller part in this extension. You can download it and can upload it to your project.

You can add `<?php echo $this->getUrl().'contacts/index/postnew'?>` in action of the form.

You can edit the email file. File Path is `app\locale\en_US\template\email\contact_form_new.html`. You can not add the `html` tag in this file.

[Download Extension.](https://github.com/vikasneoventis/Mageweb_ProductEnquiry)

For more help, please comment on this answer.

Comment: ok i am trying. But please make sure if any new error occur bcz of this extension.

Comment: If you face any issue, then you can easily disable this extension. This extension is not changing any code of your website

Comment: you can set false in `active` tag in `app > etc > modules > Mageweb_ProductEnquiry.xml` file

Comment: ok i m trying and thankyou very much

Comment: First check and if this solve your problem then say thnx :)

Comment: Hi, mail has not been sent and there is no message to display status of mail.

Comment: please check your contact email is working ?

Comment: If contact email is working, then fro testing add same fields as contact from in this form.

Comment: fields are same and contact email is working

Comment: <form class="" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl().'contacts/index/postnew'?>" method="post" id="myform">
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Enter Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" required>
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email address:</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" required>
  </div>

Comment: <div class="form-group">
    <label for="number">Phone Number:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telephone" id="telephone" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="msg">Message:</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="4" name="comment" id="comment" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <button  type="submit"   name="enquiry" > Submit</button>  
</form>

Comment: this is my form

Comment: Please share the link where you have placed form

Comment: @vikas verma ,  can you tell me how to send a review and rating form in mail and after submit review from mail directly save in to database. for more detail you can view this link :  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220373/how-to-send-a-review-form-in-mail-after-buy-products-in-magento