# How to send a review form in mail after buy products in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-review

I am using magento CE 1.9.2 and sending emails to the customers after buy a products. I want to send bought product's review rating form in mail to the customer, after fill form customer submit that form from mail and that review automatically save in magento database. Can anyone tell me how to achive this.

Thanks in advance..!

I have below peace of code which is send product detail like product image , name and sku in mail. after press **"Leave feedback"**  button it will redirect on review form of that products which i bought earlier.

I want to skip that step and send rating and review form directly in mail and after fill review and submit form from mail and that review directly save in database for particular products.

```
<?php

if (Mage::getStoreConfig('getcustomerfeedback_section1/general/custom_product_review_url'))
    {

    // custom product review url with review-form #

    $productReviewURL = Mage::app()->getStore($orderStoreID)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK) . Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($cartProductID, 'url_key', Mage::app()->getStore($orderStoreID)) . '.html/#review-form' . $urlTrackingTags;
    }
  else
    {

    // standard review product url

    $productReviewURL = Mage::app()->getStore($orderStoreID)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK) . 'review/product/list/id/' . $cartProductID . '/#review-form' . $urlTrackingTags;
    }

?>
```